# No return from the constructor in HelloCouch example

Tags: java, couchbase

Configurations:

```
Windows 7 x64 (fully updated or fresh install), JDK 7.0.450 (x64 or x86), Java SDK lib 1.2.2, Couchbase Server 2.2.0 (local or remote installation on Ubuntu Server 13.10).
```

Couchbase Lib log:

```
2013-11-27 13:49:53.961 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection: Added {QA sa=/192.168.1.126:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2013-11-27 13:49:53.989 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection: Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@148a8e6
2013-11-27 13:49:54.046 INFO com.couchbase.client.ViewConnection: Added Comp1 to connect queue
2013-11-27 13:49:54.049 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient: viewmode property isn't defined. Setting viewmode to production mode
```

Point of no return in the example:

```
CouchbaseClient client = new CouchbaseClient(hosts, bucket, password);
```

Full code of the example is [here](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/java/getting-started)

Any ideas?

P.S. On Ubuntu Server 13.10 the example works fine. So is the problem in WinAPI-JVM layer?

P.S.S. [Here is the dump of VM state](http://pastebin.com/Ua34i8HW)

Comment: What exactly is the problem: the construction of the CouchBaseClient gives a timeout? Can you post the stacktrace that you get in that case?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if the URLs in the Hosts are actually reachable? Use your browser, or curl or wget to give it a shot

Comment: @Miquel the hosts and the ports are reachable, Couchbase console works fine as for local instance of Couchbase server so for remote machine.

Comment: @ljgw that's right, the app hangs on the construction. I added the link to dump to the question body.

Comment: Avast! Free Antivirus 2014.9.0.2008 was the issue! Thx to everybody!

Comment: @AlexK would you consider closing the question? You could write a reply to your own question and mark it as the accepted answer. No worries, there's no etiquette broken or unfair rep points given to the wrong people

Comment: @Miquel unfortunately I can't close the question right now. I was noticed: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 11/27/2013 5:32:57 PM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: @AlexK no problem and welcome to StackOverflow! Don't worry, all those little annoying limitations will go away as soon as you get a little bit of rep

Answer (score 2):

Avast! Free Antivirus 2014.9.0.2008 and Kaspersky 2014 somehow locks execution of socket io WinAPI functions. So I switched to MS Security Essentials and the issue was solved. I should notice until the latest update Avast! worked fine. Thanks to everybody who was trying to solve  this case.